# post vs get for URL params?

Tags: php, html

I would like to give the user the ability to return to a previous page with pagination controls after submitting a form.  Typically I use post but this will not pass the in the URL.

Is it recommended to use get instead?

Comment: You could submit the form in POST and redirect to a page (using [`header`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)) with GET params, which would allow bookmarking.

Comment: Of course.  You can and should use `GET` for retrieval.

Comment: What kind of form? Just a search form or user details etc?

Comment: Treffynnon: Just a search form so the data doesn't need to be private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from saving the pagination information in the form. For example you are at:

```
http://mysite/list.php?page=3&maxperpage=50
```

A link on the page can redirect the user to

```
http://mysite/edit.php?id=8475&page=3&maxperpage=50
```

Save the page and maxperpage as hidden controls into the form reloading them each time you show the form (in case of postback errors)

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['page']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="maxperpage" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['maxperpage']; ?>" />
```

Then when the postback is complete, use the _POST hidden fields to redirect to that previous page:

```
header('location: http://mysite/list.php?page='.$_POST['page'].'&maxperpage='.$_POST['maxperpage']);
```

Obviously, i've skipped a lot of stuff in there such as validation so don't forget to put some in...

Comment: My form has a dozen params so should I keep a hidden control for each or simply switch to get?

Comment: You keep using GET when passing those pagination/filter/search params BUT when you get to a form such as an edit form, you push those params into hiddens fields. Then, when you are done with these hidden fields (such as after saving) you push those hidden fields back into the url and redirect the user...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a number of things, mainly what content you are passing through the form.

Generally if you have a textarea in the form, its a bad idea to send via GET as your much more likely to reach the max character limit of a URL.
And obviously if your passing a file then it needs to be POST.
Oh, and obviously if it's sensitive data (e.g. username/password) then using GET isn't a good idea.

Other than that I see no harm in using GET instead, as long as you are "cleaning" the data before using it anywhere.

If using GET isn't an option, then one thing you can do instead is use POST, but save everything in a COOKIE or SESSION variable for you to retrieve on the previous page if pagination/breadcrumbs are used after submitting the form.

Comment: I always forget about SESSION variables.  That might be a better solution except for the fact a user will not be able to bookmark correct?

Comment: @Paul exact, sessions are on the server and thus not part of the URL. And you are bookmarking a url, so i wouldn't recommend it...

Comment: @Paul no, unfortunately this means that users won't be able to bookmark the URL. The only way to provide that would be to give them a GET url.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a little on Alex and tandu's comments:

You should use POST when you are sending data the will change the state on the server.  You should use GET when you request data or are performing some other action that will leave the server state unchanged.

So, Yes you are correct to use POST for submitting your form and GET is not recommended in this case.

Then after the post redirect the user to their previous page, perhaps after a short delay to view a thank you message.

Comment: I'm basically just retrieving data from my DB and displaying it so I'm not really changing the state of the server unless I misread your post

Comment: when you said 'after submitting a from' i assumed something like a signup form.  If you are doing something like say a search form and displaying the results then you should use GET but be careful about what you add to the queryString.  this has the advantage of making the results page url save/repeate-able, so it could be added to favouries for example.  we could use more info about what you are trying to achieve with this form.